# Avoiding duplicates in different feeds with getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

Let's say I want to build a system where each user has access to a notification feed and an aggregated feed, with the following groups:

- *user* as flat feed
- *hashtag* as flat feed
- *notification* as notification feed
- *timeline* as aggregated feed

We also have the following relations:

1. *user:b* follows *hashtag:a*
2. *user:b* follows *user:a*

Now consider the following situation:

If user A posts with hashtag A, I would like user B to get an activity in its notification feed (thanks to relation 1). But I also would also like all followers of user A to see in their timeline that user A did something. Then, user B will get the activity in its notification feed, and in its timeline (because of relation 2): there is a duplicate.

Is there a way to avoid this situation ?

A naive way would be to manually filter the feed and prune the aggregated activities we do not want to see. But this of course seems non optimal.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use discard rules to avoid activities matching one of rule from getting added to a follower's feed.

This is usually something  you use to avoid own activities from showing up in your notification feed.

Here's the link to the docs on Discard Rules:
https://getstream.io/docs/#discard-rules

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think discard rules would not be enough to solve my case. In this situation, actions on the timeline are still desirable, unless the user follows the targeted hashtag in which case we want the activity to exclusively appear in the notification feed. But I don't think there is a way to define dynamic discard rules depending on the feed relationships ?

Comment: We only have the ones we list in the docs. I'll poke a devrel and see if anyone has other ideas.